# What determines track speed?

Tags: audiosurf

What determines your speed on the track? I can not find anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played dozens tracks, and  I tested manny different music.
For me, bass (with dubstep or other style like dartek) ar the speedest music i played. If you take for example, a bob marley music than a skrillex track, you'll see the difference.

I think, the speed is created by the tempo. (Try many metal track like dragonforce if you like it)